# Map JSON to the model irrespective of Array or Object - ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I am having trouble in mapping the JSON to my object class. Here is my Model Object

```
class CityObject : NSObject, Mappable{
var id : String?
var name : String?

required init?(map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
}
}
```

The JSON response I get from server sometime may be Array or an Object like this.

Array:

```
{
"cities": [
{
  "id": "190",
  "name": "Elurupadu"
},
{
  "id": "1230",
  "name": "Sendhwa"
},
{
  "id": "1262",
  "name": "Multai"
},
{
  "id": "1480",
  "name": "Kherwara"
}]
}
```

Sometimes I get like this,

```
{
"cities": {"id": "6","name": "Hyderabad"}
}
```

Instead of an JSONArray it gives me JSONObject.

I am mapping to my class like this,

```
let list = Mapper<CityObject>().mapArray(JSONObject:cities["cities"])
```

This works perfectly when I get JSONArray, but the same doesn't work when I get JSONObject.

How to handle both with ObjectMapper?

Comment: Fix your server.  It should provide a consistent schema.  Otherwise you will need to conditionally downcast to an array and if that fails, map to a dictionary

Comment: As the server is also getting this response from third party, fixing at server end is not possible as of now, Can you provide a small code snippet to have a checker at my end?

Comment: @Neo even if your server receives data from third party, before sending it to your app, you could check if you receive an array of dictionaries or a single dictionary on server side and if it's a single dictionary, wrap it in an array so that your app receives an array of a single dictionary in this case. Or if you really can't change anything on the server side, just check if `mapArray` succeeds and if not, parse *cities* as a single dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Paulw11 suggestion down casting to MAP worked for me.

```
if let list = Mapper<CityObject>().mapArray(JSONObject:cities["cities"]){
   //Handles JSONArray response
}
else if let list = Mapper<CityObject>().map(JSONObject: cities["cities"]){
  //Handles JSONObject response
}
else{
  //Handles error
}
```